# how to find different data in different sheets in excel

Tags: excel

hello i have a quite problem on excel files.
i have 2 different sheets on excel files, i call it A sheets and B sheets and there is an tables of data including Name Column. i wanted to compare the sheets in A into B if they missing the data, so i can easy to find what data is missing in B Table on B sheets. because i using manually ctrl+f way too longer because i have thousand of data to compare

i hope my explanations cleary enough

[the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfKik.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula and let us know your feedback.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(SheetA!A1,$A$1:$A$20,0)),"Exist","Missing")
```

Comment: where i should apply this formula ?

Comment: SheetB `B1` cell. If it works then you can modify as your need.